# Haskell: define foldM in do-notation

Tags: haskell, recursion, bind

I am confused about defining `foldM` in a do-block, mainly because of its recursion. The standard definition for `foldM` is as follows:

```
foldM             :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
foldM _ a []      =  return a
foldM f a (x:xs)  =  f a x >>= \fax -> foldM f fax xs
```

I understand this definition; the result of `f a x` is passed into a new `foldM` function recursively, until the list is empty. Here is a definition of `foldM` in a do-block (copied from my uni course material):

```
foldM _ z []     = return z
foldM f z (x:xs) = do r <- foldM f z xs
                      f r x
```

I know that the definition of a do block is basically syntactic sugar for bind `(>>=)` operations. However, I can't seem to grasp how this definition works. I find recursion in do-blocks overall very confusing. What is given to `r`? How can the recursive line `r <- foldM f z xs` be correct when `foldM` is passed `z` every recursive call? Shouldn't it be passed a recursively updated argument like `f z x`, as in the `foldM` definition with `(>>=)`?

Comment: The definition in your course material defines a different function that does something else. You are right to be suspicious. I challenge you to prove they're different by calling each with the same arguments and getting different results.

Comment: I challenge you also to write a `do`-based version of `foldM` that's equivalent to the usual definition.

Answer (score 2):

The latter variant evaluates the actions on the list from right-to-left, whereas the other one evaluates the actions on the list from right-to-left. Let's call the latter `foldMDo`, so that we can keep them apart:

```
foldM             :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
foldM _ a []      =  return a
foldM f a (x:xs)  =  f a x >>= \fax -> foldM f fax xs

foldMDo _ z []     = return z
foldMDo f z (x:xs) = do r <- foldMDo f z xs
                      f r x
```

If we use them to print a list, the difference is immediately obvious:

```
ghci> foldM (\_ y -> print y) () [1..10]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

ghci> foldMDo (\_ y -> print y) () [1..10]
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

So, let's desugar the `do` variant:

```
do r <- foldMDo f z xs
   f r x
```

is the same as

```
foldMDo f z xs >>= \fzxs -> f fzxs x
```

Let's compare this to the other one next to each other:

```
(1) f a x          >>= \fax  -> foldM f fax  xs
(2) foldMDo f z xs >>= \fzxs ->       f fzxs x
```

We can compare that to `foldl` and `foldr` with explicit `let...in`:

```
foldr f a (x:xs) = let acc = foldr f a xs
                   in f a acc
foldl f a (x:xs) = let acc = f a x
                   in foldr f acc xs
```

The uni material looks like `foldr`, whereas the default one looks like `foldl`, as it is expected with the order of evaluation.

And for completion, let's add the `do` version of your `foldM`:

```
foldM f a (x:xs) = do fax <- f a x
                      foldM f fax xs
```

## TL;DR

Your uni course material doesn't implement `foldM`, since it doesn't do left-to-right evaluation, but instead right-to-left. Essentially,

Comment: Whereas `foldl` can be implemented in terms of `foldr`, I don't think either `foldM` or `foldMDo` can be implemented in terms of the other. A monad with failure allows `foldM` to terminate with an infinite list (sometimes), while a monad with left-lazy `>>=` allows `foldMDo` to terminate with an infinite list (sometimes). Of course, both `foldM` and `foldMDo` can be implemented in terms of `foldr`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What still confuses me about the foldMDo function is that, taking your 'print' function as an example, there is just 1 line that actually prints the ints: `f r x`. How and when are all 10 ints printed? Is the entire bind chain of `r <- foldMDo f z xs` evaluated once, or is the do-block recursively called 10 times?